# How to get the content of a notification on a smartphone?

Tags: android, notifications, smartphone, mobile-phones

I would like to create a budget dynamically updated at each transaction.

First of all, I was thinking of create an automate with PowerAutomate, which get the content of an e-mail (container all the information of a transaction) and then update an Excel file automatically.

It works but I wanted to upgrade it by getting the content of the notification that pops up after a transaction to update an Excel file.

How is it possible to collect the content of a notification ? Which environment to use to handle it ?

Owen

Comment: You have added Android and iPhone tag - both platforms are totally different so please restrict your question to one platform.